# Ionic 5 push notifications with Capacitor

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, capacitor

My Ionic 5 app wants to send push notifications. The only guide I could find for this is [Using Push Notifications with Firebase in an Ionic + Angular App](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/guides/push-notifications-firebase/)

Why is Firebase necessary? Can I send push notifications without Firebase?

I tried this setup anyway. I didn't get very far.

The guide has this code:

```
    // Request permission to use push notifications
    // iOS will prompt user and return if they granted permission or not
    // Android will just grant without prompting
    PushNotifications.requestPermission().then( result => {
      if (result.granted) {
        // Register with Apple / Google to receive push via APNS/FCM
        PushNotifications.register();
      } else {
        // Show some error
      }
    });
```

However, Typescript is complaining that the correct method is `requestPermissions()` not `requestPermission()`.

Both fail when running in XCode, probably because I didn't set up pods.

What are my options with Ionic 5 + Capacitor for sending push notifications without Firebase?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT:

The guide is now updated to Capacitor 3.

Capacitor 2 guide can be found [here](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/v2/guides/push-notifications-firebase)

OLD:
The guide has been updated to capacitor 2, but capacitor 2 is still in beta.

Install it using next tag

```
npm install @capacitor/cli@next
npm install @capacitor/core@next
npm install @capacitor/ios@next
npm install @capacitor/android@next
```

Capacitor uses APNS by default, so if you don’t make the changes in the AppDelegate.swift it should just work.

Comment: Why is Firebase necessary? Can I send notifications directly through Apple / Android notification centers without going through Firebase?

Comment: That’s a firebase guide because people wanted to know how to use firebase on iOS and somebody wrote that guide, but as I said, iOS uses APNS (Apple Push Notification Service) by default. Android uses firebase because that’s what google says you have to use, they killed GCM a year ago, not sure what “android Notification Center” is

Comment: Capacitor code is the same whether you use APNS or firebase, but the guide explains how to add the dependency and how to get a firebase token, so as long as you don’t make the native changes the same JavaScript code will work